# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass schneems reddit example

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I thought that adding `@links=Link.all` to my controller would fix this problem.
I did make sure that I have valid entries in my Link DB by looking at `Link.count=6`

I am getting the following error:

NoMethodError in Pages#index
 Showing /Projects/reddit_on_rails/app/views/pages/index.html.erb where line #6 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

```
<ul>
<% @links.each do |link| %>
<li>link.url</li>
<li>link.title</li>
<% end %>
```

My controller:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  #Added @links =Link.all  did not solve the problem

  def index
    @links = Link.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @link = Link.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @link }
    end
  end

  def create
    @link = Link.new(link_params)

    if @link.save
      #render "new"
      redirect_to "/"
    else
      # This line overrides the default rendering behavior, which
      # would have been to render the "create" view.
      render "new"
    end
  end

 private

   def link_params
     params.require(:link).permit(:title,:url)
   end 
end
```

Comment: love the way that you put the story

Comment: Which action are you accessing to create this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you got following error message

```
NoMethodError in Pages#index
Showing /Projects/reddit_on_rails/app/views/pages/index.html.erb where line #6 raised:
```

According to error message you have problem in `Pages` controller inside `index` method. So you need to fix the problem inside `Pages` controller not inside `Links` controller.

Do you have method called `index` inside your `Pages` controller?

Comment: That was easy.  I wasted so many hours playing around with links_controller   THANKS

Answer (score 0):

`@links` is `nil` because you are not setting it anywhere in your controller with something like `@links = Link.all`.

You cannot call `each` on `nil`.

Comment: That that would have solved the problem but adding @links=Link.all did not help

Answer (score 0):

What view are you in? Assuming index.html.erb.

in your controller, try adding

```
def index
  @link = Link.all
end
```

If that doesn't work, verify you have any links at all. In terminal instead of typing `rails server` type

```
rails console
Link.all
```

If that comes back as `[]` then you don't have any in your database.

Comment: thanks    I think that was my first problem I added the @link to my controller but that did not seem to fix it .  And I have several valid entries in my DB  (Link.count = 6)